# Google Spreadsheets - Determining years since date value in another cell

Tags: date, google-sheets

I have cells with date values formatted as DD/MM/YYYY. What I need is to use that value to determine the number of years that have passed since that date as of Jan 1st of the current year.

For example.
4-4-2010 - the value I should see is 3 since only 3 years had passed as of Jan 1st 2014.
But when I open the spreadsheet next year on Jan 2nd it should show 4 since another year will have passed.
I don't need to see months or any increments of years. Just a whole number.

Comment: Which is it, DD/MM/YYYY or D-M-YYYY?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DD/MM/YYYY isn't really supported as a date format by Google Sheets (at least from what I've seen, correct me if I'm wrong.  How can you identify if something is DD/MM/YYYY or MM/DD/YYYY when neither DD or MM is > 12?).  But since all you're trying to do is get the number of years since a certain year, all you have to do is extract the year from the cell you're looking at and subtract that from the current year.

Assuming the date you using is in cell A1:

```
=year(now()) - year(A1)
```

Comment: This is the formula I ended up using - =IF(YEAR(Sheet1!B$2) = YEAR(NOW()), 0, DATEDIF(Sheet1!B$2,DATE(YEAR(NOW()), 1, 1), "Y"))